# Problems with Query Command ORDER BY in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm working with one Spreadsheet named "geral" (General, in Portuguese), where I saved all informations and the column A saves the Names of the people. I created another sheet just to see some columns from 'Geral' Sheet, and I entered the following formula in A1 cell:

```
=QUERY(geral!1:994; "select A,F,L,M order by A"; 1)
```

. It doesn't work, but if I wrote `... order by A desc` it works well.

How can I write the query to see the data in "ABC" order, and not just descending?

Answer (score 24):

Look lower down your sheet. Blanks are being sorted first.

Comment: To add, use `"select * where A <> '' or A is not null order by A"` to filter out empty cells

Comment: that is embarrassing